# Sublime Text 3 sidebar stuck and freeeze

Tags: editor, sidebar

After switching between projects I get this problem:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAa9k.png)

Sometimes Sublime Text restart fix this issue but today It did not help. I am not able to use sidebar, It just stuck. It is strange that when you open "Find dialog box" (at the bottom), folders and files appear on Sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Preferences > Settings - User

```
"ignore_inodes": true
```

**Edit**: Another option can be to create a new workspace

[image: workaround]